# Add css to 1 page using scss and ReactJS and redux

Tags: css, html, reactjs, sass, redux

I am using ReactJS with redux.
I using scss.
lets say my path is:
http://localhost:3000/login
I need to add to this page:
html:{ overflow:hidden}

and on other pages i want to remove this attribute.

Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the style attribute of the html tag:

```
class MyPage extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.htmlTag = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    this.htmlTag.setAttribute('style', 'overflow: hidden');  
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.htmlTag.setAttribute('style', '');
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is your project architecture, but you can add a class (className) into your HTML tag in differently ways.

If you want, you can also use your redux state.
You check if you are in X page, if it's ok, pass a boolean at true and if it's true, put your css.

I prefer the first solution.

Comment: The answer is clarify by Luke Vella under my answer =)

Answer (score 0):

You could just import a className, let's say `loginStyle`, and make it so:

`html: {
    overflow: hidden;
}`

Then, you just put it as a condition let's say on your header (has to be an element present in every page).

Something like

`const isLogin = window.location.pathname === login ? true : false` ( <= this is not the real condition, but make it so `isLogin` equals true is you are on your login page).

`<Header className={`${className1} ${className2} ${isLogin ? loginStyle : ' '}`}/>`

And your style will only be applied on your login page. Maybe not the simpliest, but at least this would work :)